# Strange C++ reference invalidation on return

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference

Have a look at the following code. The goal here is to return a reference through two functions (from `ReferenceProvider::getReference()` to `getRef()` to `main()`):

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>

class BaseClass {
public:
  virtual void write() const {
    printf("In base class\n");
  }
};
typedef BaseClass* BaseClassPointer;

class ChildClass : public BaseClass {
public:
  virtual void write() const {
    printf("In child class\n");
  }
};
typedef ChildClass* ChildClassPointer;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ChildClass* g_somePointer = new ChildClass();

class ReferenceProvider {
public:
  const BaseClassPointer& getReference() {
    const BaseClassPointer& val = g_somePointer;
    return val;
  }
};

ReferenceProvider g_provider;

const BaseClassPointer& getRef() {
  std::string test;

  const BaseClassPointer& val = g_provider.getReference();
  return val;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  BaseClass* child = getRef();

  assert(child == g_somePointer);
  child->write();

  return 0;
}
```

Now, when debugging this code (in Visual C++), breaking at `return val;` in `getRef()` will give you a screen like this:

[image: Breaking a return]

Notice how the values of `g_somePointer` and `val` are the same. Now, step over the return statement and you'll get a screen like this:

[image: Breaking after return]

Notice how `val` has become invalid (`0xcccccccc`). This is probably because the stack of `getRef()` has been cleared and `val` is no longer available.

The problem now is that `child` in `_tmain()` will get this invalid value (`0xcccccccc`) rendering `child` unusable. So my first (and main) question is: *How to do this correctly?*

(Please note that this is just an boiled down example from some other code I've been working on. It needs to be structured like with, including using references to pointers.)

What's making this whole thing very strange (and hard to debug) is that the function `getRef()` works under some conditions:

1. If you change the type of `g_somePointer` to `BaseClass*` (from `ChildClass*`)
2. If you remove the local variable in `getRef()` (i.e. the line `std::string test;`)

In both cases the reference variable `val` (in `getRef()`) will *not* become invalid and the function will return the correct pointer address. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to write Java in C++. I hope you're not doing it by choice. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with C++; I can't switch to Java (although I'd love to as C++ is driving me crazy ;) )

Comment: Well, your other option is to learn C++ *the right way*. Treating it as Java is a recipe for pain and suffering. But when used "normally", it's not too bad

Comment: What's so "Java" in this code?

Comment: Everything? I mean, what's the use of the global variables? Why the `ReferenceProvider`? Why `printf`? Why all that useless boilerplate code that doesn't achieve anything?

Comment: (1) the reliance on pointer/reference semantics everywhere. In C++, you should generally return (and often pass) by value. (2) using `new` all over the place. In C++, you should generally use smart pointers to wrap memory allocations, or write RAII-style objects which encapsulate resources such as memory allocations to ensure they're freed again, and (3) the insistence on putting *all* functions inside classes, and using huge inheritance hierarchies and virtual functions all over the place. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Because its a boiled down example. This isn't the whole code, its just enough to show the problem. This is exactly why I wrote the note in the question, because there are always people who think that this thing above there is the whole code.

Comment: @jalf: I don't see your point. Just like I said, it's an example. And are you telling me that in your opinion C++ programs should work without inheritance? Seriously? I thought this was the point of C++.

Comment: No. C++ is a multi-paradigm language for a reason, and doesn't restrict itself to OOP only. *And that is A Good Thing™.* We have generic programming, we have procedural programming, we have OOP, we have functional-style programming and possibly much more. OOP is not the One-True-Paradigm.

Comment: But in my case I need to use OOP.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: my point is that you are making life extremely difficult for yourself by trying to force it to do something it isn't designed for. And no, inheritance is not the point of C++. Far from it. It is a tool, an occasionally useful one, but certainly not something you would usually design your software around. If you are willing to drop all your assumptions about the language and try to learn it on its own merits, instead of as a Java-lite, I can promise you that your C++ code will be simpler, more readable, much less buggy and not least, *a lot* shorter. :)

Comment: I realize that you may not have the option to completely redesign your code at this stage, but I'm telling you because it may help you out in the future. :)

Comment: @jalf: I'm sorry, I was a little frustrated yesterday. My correct answer should have been: "Unfortunately, I don't think that I can do this without this kind of design." I'm trying (or better: tried) to write a wrapper for an STL iterator which required templates, inheritance, and references.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: outof curiosity, for which purpose? There's little to be gained by trying to wrap them or giving them a different interface

Comment: @jalf: Because I need to iterate over a collection of objects for which I only know the base class.

Comment: That shouldn't affect the iterators at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const BaseClassPointer& val = g_somePointer;
```

Since `g_somePointer` has a different type (`ChildClass*` is convertible to `BaseClass*`, but is not the same type), `val` cannot refer directly to `g_somePointer`. Instead, a temporary copy is made, converted to the correct type, and `val` refers to that.

The temporary only lasts as long as `val`, going out of scope at the end of the function, so the function returns an invalid reference.

> If you change the type of g_somePointer to BaseClass* (from ChildClass*)

In that case, no pointer conversion is required, and so `val` can refer directly to `g_somePointer`. The code is then correct, but fragile.

> If you remove the local variable in getRef() (i.e. the line std::string test;)

With the string variable, there is a destructor call at the end of the function, which overwrites the defunct stack frame that contains the temporary pointer. Without it, nothing overwrites the memory, so the code appears to work - which is unfortunate, as it makes the error much harder to notice.

Comment: The rules on coercing pointer types, compared to pointer- (or reference-) -to-pointer types, aren't intuitive and can easily catch you out. FWIW it would anyway be _dangerous_ to return a ref-to-base-class-pointer bound to a derived class pointer: the caller could reset the pointer to a base-class instance and the compiler couldn't tell it was wrong.

Comment: But then why does `val` contain the address of the `g_somePointer`?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: It doesn't. There are two pointers, (`g_somePointer` and the temporary that `val` refers to), located at different addresses, which both have the same value (i.e. both point to the same location, the object created by the `new ChildClass` expression). The debugger is displaying the pointers' values, not their locations.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Ok, so I can't return references this way?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: You can, if you're very careful. It must be a reference to a persistent object (static, global, or a class member), and the type must be an exact match. In this case, there's absolutely no point in returning a `const` reference - just return by value.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: In my full code BaseClassPointer would be a template argument so I can't just return a copy to it. This only works if the template argument is a pointer (or a class that supports copying).

Comment: Having issues with pointers, references and inheritance, is adding templates to the table really a good idea ?

Comment: @ereOn: Do I really need to answer this? Yes it is. Otherwise I wouldn't have done it.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: are you saying that you never do anything that's a bad idea? That makes you unique among all the programmers I've ever met.

Answer (score 3):

You can never return a reference to a local object: it will always go out of scope when the function is exited. Sometimes it may appear as if it works but this is just because the data is normally not change when the stack pointer is adjusted.

Comment: Well, `g_somePointer` is hardly a local object. Or are you saying that there's no way of passing a reference as return value?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: You can obviously pass a reference as a return value. Now you have to ensure that the reference is still valid when the function returns and it will not be the case if you return a reference to a stack-allocated object within the function call.

Comment: @ereOn: This I completely understand. I just wasn't sure whether I return the reference to the local stack variable or to the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

To explain what's going on:

```
const BaseClassPointer& val = g_somePointer;
```

This line is the problem. Let's do away with the typedef:

```
BaseClass* const& val = g_somePointer;
```

Here, the type of `g_somePointer` is `ChildClass*`. In order to assign it to a `BaseClass*`, a conversion is needed. From that conversion, a temporary pointer is introduced. That pointer is bound to a reference-to-const, which extends the temporaries lifetime *until the reference dies*, which is exactly the case after your `return val;` statement. At that point, the temporary base-class pointer doesn't exist anymore and you have undefined behaviour.

To avoid all that mess, just return a `BaseClass*`.

Comment: You are correct that there is no guarantee that a base-class pointer contains the same address as a derived-class pointer. That said, comparing pointers for equality like this is fine, because the derived-class pointer will be converted to a base-class pointer before the comparison.

Comment: @Mankarse: Good point, I forgot how pointers worked here for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do something like that. Returning a reference to local memory is the same as returning the address of local memory, which is undefined behavior.  All sorts of things can go wrong (or by chance, things can go right).

Comment: That's the question here. If I return a variable that is a reference type, will I return the reference to that local variable or will I return the reference it contains.

Comment: @MGZero: I would rather say "By lack of chance, things can go right" because when this happens, it usually stops working when you least expect it.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: No offense, but it seems you are trying to create some very complex while you have very little understanding of the base C++ principles. You should probably put aside your Java background if you want to master these concepts in C++ as they differ **a lot**.

Comment: @ereOn: That's why I'm asking this question here. If I knew another way of doing it, I would. But I can't think of another way and I doubt there is one.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: You current design seems needlessly complicated and does not look like C++ at all. There is nothing wrong doing Java, there is nothing wrong doing C++ : but mixing both is awful, error prone and suboptimal. If you are not used to C++, perhaps you should rather ask for generic design advices **first** at is seems that you currently want to use OOP, references, pointers where it is probably not needed.

Comment: @ereOn: Why do you assume you're so much smarter than I? And why do you think the code example above (remember: boiled down) is complete? It's just a piece of a larger code segment. And in the full code it does make sense. I just didn't want to drop the whole 1000 lines of code here, but thought it would be nice to reduce it to the main problem. But apparently I'm the only one getting that.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski: I never said anything about our respective smartnesses. Did I ? If you have a problem, and ask for an answer: there is nothing wrong with that. But here, you have a problem, a broken solution you came up with and want us to fix it without suggesting anything else. C++ is not Java. Neither is good or wrong. But the general logic differs. So yes, no one can stop you from doing C++ the Java way, but when 15 different people try to explain you why this is wrong, it might be a good idea to at least consider you can be wrong from the very start. And that includes your design.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski I'm sorry, but in the context of C++, regardless of the full picture, your design does not make sense.  What you are doing is not defined by the standard and therefore non standard things can happen.  We've answered your question, so you can choose to accept it or leave it.

Comment: @MGZero: Its not about the answers to my question. I totally understand that I can't use references like I did in the example above. Its just that everyone thinks to know what my whole design looks like just by looking at a fraction of it.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski It isn't necessary for us to look at your entire design to make the assumption that was made.  Your code doesn't look like C++.  It's obvious you're coming from a Java background and are using that style from your use of references and printf.  This argument is honestly kind of silly, and it isn't really helping you any.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "val" to "survive", getReference() method should return a reference to a static object. Is that "static" going to work in your current architecture is another question.

Comment: The object `getReference()` is returning is `static` (when you're using `static` as in "static field of a class").

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a const reference to the local `val` instead of the returned `getRef()`.

Also, how do you transform the pointer to a reference?

```
const BaseClassPointer& val = g_somePointer;
return val;
```

won't work if g_somePointer is a pointer - did you use `*g_somePointer` or similar?

Comment: A sorry - of course it is... so using a reference to a pointer. I don't get the point why this would make sense? ;)

Comment: @Coder02: It's because in the complete code BaseClassPointer would be a template argument. And this can be a pointer or not a pointer.